# Laravel 5.3 FileNotFoundException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am uploading an image to local storage as

```
$path = $request->image->store('images');
```

Image gets stored in storage/app/images/name.extension

However my problem is showing this image to the user, I am getting file not found exception

I tried, asset, Storage:get, Storage::url and etc.

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you followed the laravel documentation?

Comment: Yes I did, I followed and then am asking it here.

Comment: According to Laravel documentation the public storage files are stored in storage/app/public`


You should use the public disk in your storage operations.


`Storage::disk('public')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');`


or configure the `public` disk as the default filesystem.

Comment: @motie Thanks your suggestion helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was I was storing files in **storage/app/images** directory instead of **storage/app/public/images** and finally I retrieved using

```
asset('storage/'.$image-name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link to the `storage/app/images/` from the `public` directory.

`ln -s storage/images public/images`

Comment: I did that using php artisan storage:link even after that I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Storage::get('/images/'.$filename);
```

or

```
Storage::get('/app/images/'.$filename);
```

Comment: try to give permission to storage